# H1 tag no longer showing on page body

Tags: html, css

So I've created a div called ".content" and I want it to display some text, but for some reason it wont show up... Maby I'm just stupid but could someone help me.

[image: Screenshot:]

```css
.content{
    color: black;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: "Luna";
}
```

```html
<header>  
  <div class="variation-a">
    <button class="suit_and_tie">About Me</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happening here is you preserving your child element in 3D space, and it seem like the `header::background` is overlaping your `.content` element.

```
perspective: 1px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

You must bring your `.content` element forward by apply `transform: translateZ()`

```
.content{
 transform: translateZ(30px)
}
```

Additionally, `transform` is likely to always go with [transform-style:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)

Comment: I do have an opening <header> tag, this is only a section of the code that I shared where I was experiencing the problem.

Comment: As you see in my snippets,  the H1 text is showing, so i think the code you post work fine. Can you open the browser developer tool and check that `H1` element css to see if it is overrided by any `display / opacity / z-index` property ?

Comment: Hello, I don't see anything, here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/oeiuap

Comment: Try changing the `H1` color to white to see if it show up

Comment: `color: white` still nothing... It seems to be underneath my header picture tho... Is there a styling proposition I could use to make it come out underneath the header?

Comment: Yes `z-index: 1` will bring it forward all element with `z-index:0` which is the default value. Try apply it with like `z-index: 1000`.

Comment: Could you find anything of interest?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will help

Comment: The right property to apply here is `transform: translateZ(30px)` to your element. If you tend to keep the `transform-style` property